# Deploying meteor.js app using `meteor`

Tags: node.js, meteor

I was thinking whether we can deploy Meteor.js app doing this:

1. `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`
2. `meteor create myApp`
3. `cd myApp`
4. FTP app files into `myApp` directory
5. `meteor`

Comment: Instead of doing the ftp, why don't you just check out the app files from wherever you are getting them in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean if I'm using git in my development workflow, I should use git to deploy the files and changes into `myApp` directory?

Comment: Yes. Or you may just want to use https://npmjs.org/package/meteor-deploy. Also, be aware of the differences between the development environment and production environment of meteor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14876259/586086

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to deploy to your own server.  Therefore your need to create the bundle which you can them FTP and expand in your server/directory as follows:

1. create the bundle: meteor bundle myApp.tgz
2. FTP myApp.tgz into your server/directory.
3. Locate the uploaded tar file and extract it with the following command:
   tar -zxvf nameofyourapp.tgz

Note: If the machine you developed the application is different than the machine you are deploying to, you will need to rebuild the native package.  To do this, enter the bundle/programs/server/node_modules directory.
cd bundle/programs/server/node_modules
Once there remove the fibers directory
rm -r fibers
Rebuild fibers using npm:
npm install fibers
This will install the latest fibers version, specific to the platform you are deploying to.

Best regards,
Vince

Comment: The question is not about the official bundling process, but whether it would be appropriate to just copy over the sources and run `meteor` and I believe the comments actually serve the purpose of providing a fairly complete answer.