# How run multiple meteor servers on different ports

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

How can meteor run on multiple ports.For example if the meteor run on 3000 i need another meteor app run on the same terminal.Please help me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `--port` parameter:

```
`meteor run --port 3030`
```

To learn more about command line parameters, run `meteor help <command>`, e.g. `meteor help run`.

I see you've tagged your question [meteor-up](/questions/tagged/meteor-up). If you're actually using `mup`, check out the `env` parameter in the [config file](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/blob/master/README.md#example-file).

Comment: related question: Is it possible to run same app(two instances) in different ports? I tried to run same app in 3000 and 5000 ports and second one is showing errors related to mongodb

Comment: It's definitely possible; I have several apps that run on my website. Your app instances probably conflict while use the same database though - hence the Mongo errors.

Comment: getting this error "Exception in callback of async function: Error: connection closed" @Dan Dascalescu

Comment: How can we run the several apps on the same server please give me example.we are running single app at time.please help me @dan-dascalescu

Comment: That is a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151621/what-are-the-major-steps-required-to-create-multiple-instances-of-a-meteor-js-ap); see [this](http://code.krister.ee/hosting-multiple-instances-of-meteor-on-digitalocean/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/lNUXckZpAO4).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the settings.json file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP was referring to the exceptions caused because of locks on the mongo db.   I am only on this platform for last week - and am learning as quick as I can.  But when I tried running my application from the same project directory as two different users on two different ports - I got an exception about MongoDB :

**Error: EBUSY, unlink**  'D:\test\.meteor\local\db\mongod.lock'

The root of the issue isn't running on different ports - it is the shared files between the two instances - Specifically the database.

I don't think any of your answers actually helped him out.  And .. neither can I yet.

I see two options -

First -

I am going to experiment with links to see if I can get the two users to use a different folder for the *.meteor\local*   tree ... so both of us can work on the same code at the same time - but not impact each other when testing.

But I doubt if that is what the OP was referring to either (different users same app)...

Second - is trying to identify if I can inject into the run-mongo.js some concept of the URL / port number I am running on, so the mongodb.lock (and db of course) ... are named something like   mongodb.lock-3000

I don't like the 2nd option because then I am on my own version of standard scripts.

B

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's more appropriate as a few comments.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is mainly used the default port of 3000 or any state at the start, and the following (+1) to Mongo.
That is, the following application can be run through a 2-port, already in 3002, hence the previous 2-port as before - it is 2998.

Check can be very simple (Mac, Linux):

```
ps|grep meteor
```

Comment: Lord, that distribute cons, please unsubscribe in the comments, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just use different db instance (set **METEOR_LOCAL_DIR**)

```json
 "devOne": "export METEOR_LOCAL_DIR=.meteor/local/db2 && meteor --settings settings1.json --port 3000",
 "devTwo": "meteor --settings settings2.json --port 4000"
```